# Object from Aeson has been imported but the compiler says it's not

Tags: haskell

I'm importing this:

```
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON(..), FromJSON(..), (.:), (.=), object, Object(..), decode)
```

And I have this:

```
instance FromJSON Data123 where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    Data123 <$> v .: "a"
      <*> v .: "b"
      <*> v .: "c"

  parseJSON _ = mzero

instance ToJSON Data123 where
  toJSON (Data123 a b c) =
    object ["a" .= a
      , "b" .= b
      , "c" .= c
    ]
```

And I have an error saying

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Object’
    Perhaps you meant variable ‘object’ (imported from Data.Aeson)
```

Haven't I imported it already?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Believe it or not, you have *not* imported it yet. The [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.4/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:Object) data constructor constructs a `Value`, so to import it, you should

```
import Data.Aeson (Value(Object))
```

or similar. You probably thought that you would get it from

```
import Data.Aeson (Object(..))
```

but this in fact imports the [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.4/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Object) *type alias*. Syntactically it also appears to be trying to import any data constructors associated with the `Object` type -- but since it is an alias, there are none. (I think I might prefer if GHC issued a warning for this kind of thing!)